# Prove that $ |x-a|<b \iff x∈(a-b,a+b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I am not sure if I am doing this correctly,

my forward proof is:

Since $|x-a|$ is an absolute value function, it can be defined as $|x-a|:= \max\{(x-a),-(x-a)\}$ .

Let $S={(x-a) ∈ ℝ}$ and $b ∈ S, b>0,$

then $ x-a>b

```
     x>b+a $

 2.-(x-a)>b

   -x+a>b

   -x>b-a

    x<a-b
```

which prove that x ∈ (a − b, a + b)

Am I doing this correctly, and how can I prove the backward?

Edit:
What I am thinking about the backward equation:

a-b < x , then a-b-x<0,  next -(a-b-x)>0,  so -(a-b-x)>(a-b-x) -->max = a-b-x

a+b>x , then a+b-x<0,  next -(a+b-x)>0,  so -(a+b-x)>(a-b-x) --> max= a+b-x

then I am stuck.

Comment: I couldn't understand your proof. Why is $x-a > b$?

Comment: In general, $|r| < s$ if and only if $-s < r < s$. Prove this (if needed) and then apply to your problem.

Comment: Since(x-a) is the max, which means any value will be less than that.

Comment: Max of what?$\ \ \ $

Comment: Maximum of the function (x-a)

Comment: $(x-a)$ is the maximum of $(x-a)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to have $b > 0$ or the interval $(a - b, a + b)$ would not be expressed sensibly.

Recall that $|x-a| < b$ means that $-b < x-a < b$, after which we can add $a$ to obtain the chain of inequalities $a - b < x < a + b$, which says that $x \in (a-b, a+b)$ when rewritten using interval notation.

Comment: We need to have $b>0$ or the inequality would have no solution at all.

Comment: @egreg It is true that there are no solutions if $|x-a| < 0$, but the issue that I point to is slightly different: the notation for an open interval $(a-b, a+b)$ is not well defined unless $a+b > a-b$, i.e., $b > 0$.

Comment: One can contend that $(3,2)=\emptyset$; more generally that $(p,q)=\emptyset$ when $p\ge q$. With this convention, the statement in the question also holds for $b\le0$.

Comment: So is this the forward proof? How can I do the reverse proof?

Comment: @MathAvengers Each implication is iff; so, $x \in (a-b, a+b)$ means $a-b < x < a+b$ means $-b < x-a < b$ means $|x-a| < b$ as desired.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman oh, I got it now ! But is there a way that I can use the definition of the maximum ? (i.e. |x|:=max{x,-x})

Comment: @MathAvengers The norm on MSE is to put your thinking into the body of the post, and to avoid comments for extended discussion.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Assuming that $b > 0$, we have:

\begin{align*}
|x-a| < b \Longleftrightarrow |x-a|^{2} < b^{2} \Longleftrightarrow (x-a)^{2} - b^{2} < 0 \Longleftrightarrow (x - a - b)(x - a + b) < 0
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Take for granted* that $$|t|<c\iff-c<t<c$$

and plug

$$t=x-a, c=b.$$

---

*If you don't want to,

- $t\ge0\implies |t|=t\implies t<c$;
- $t\le0\implies |t|=-t\implies -t<c\implies -c<t$.